# Can't connect to elasticsearch by java with springboot, say can not find xxx.jar

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to study elasticsearch quickly, and I know use the springboot is fast, so I created a project with springboot, then, I look the api of elasticsearch, but,finally,its throwing a exception.

I just only want to study elasticSearch.
I dont't know if is conflict jar.
what can i do?

```
package com.test.Search;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress;
import org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;


@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class AppController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    String home() throws UnknownHostException {

        PreBuiltTransportClient client = new 
PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY);
        client.addTransportAddress(new 
InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));
        client.close();

        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(AppController.class, args);
    }
}
```

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>Search</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>Search</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
     <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
     <version>5.2.1</version>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
      <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.1</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependency>
 </dependencies>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals><goal>shade</goal></goals>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
  
</project>
```

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.plugins.NetworkPlugin

Answer (score 0):

```
Add the following in pom.xml
<dependency>
<groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
<artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
<version>5.6.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
<artifactId>transport</artifactId>
<version>5.6.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
<version>2.9.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
<version>2.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```